# Oracle Apex 19 - lov does not read another lov selected value

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex 19.
On a page i have two LOV's (List Of Values). The second LOV is loaded with a function which have to read the value given from the first LOV. Setting the second LOV as parent cascading LOV for the first LOV did not help. After introducing an on_change Dynamic Action that submits the page it seems to run correctly but it's too early for the page values that could not be complete.

Answer (score 0):

You should use cascading List Of Values.

Comment: Thank you tefek. Sorry me for so few details. I edited the question with this information. Setting Cascading LOV did not help.